# How to change the .ts file names in side the m3u8 file

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg, cmd.exe

Recently  I am using FFmpeg for a project. I used FFmpeg to convert mp3 bitrates and other stuff. Those are working perfectly. But now I want to add `mp3%2Fmusic%2F[outputN.ts]?alt=media` for every `outputN.ts` texts inside the m3u8 file.
This my m3u8 file data structure,

```
#EXTM3U

#EXT-X-VERSION:3
 
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
 
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
 
#EXTINF:2.005333,
 
'output000.ts'
 
#EXTINF:2.005333,
 
'output001.ts'
```

For Example,
, Now I want to apply `mp3%2Fmusic%2F` and `?alt=media` for every text (`output000.ts`,`output001.ts` and so on) inside this m3u8 file using windows cmd.
For instance

```
#EXTINF:2.005333,

mp3%2Fmusic%2Foutput000.ts?alt=media

#EXTINF:2.005333,

mp3%2Fmusic%2Foutput001.ts?alt=media
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bat
@echo off 

cd /d "D:\Folder\Where\Your\files\m3u8\are" && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

>tmp.m3u8 (for /f tokens^=*eol^= %%# in (file.m3u8)do echo\%%~#|findstr /e [0-9]\.ts'>nul && (
set "_out=%%~#" && cmd.exe /v /s /c "echo\mp3%%2Fmusic%%2F!_out:'=!?alt=media") || echo\%%~# )
    
>nul move /y tmp.m3u8 file.m3u8 & endlocal
```

**1.** use a `for /f` to get the listing one by one of the lines in your file:

```bat
for /f tokens^=*eol^= %%# in (file.m3u8)do ...
```

**2.** You can use an `echo\` for the current line (`%%~#`), and direct to a `findstr /e` with regex to find filter lines ending with `[numbers].ts'`

```bat
echo\%%#|findstr /e .[0-9]\.ts' >nul
```

**3.** Using the `&&` and `||` operators (is the same `return 0` / `return non 0`), when in the line currently in loop the string is found by `findstr` (`&&`), the replacement will be made, if not, the same line will be kept unchanged.

```bat
echo\%%~#|findstr /e [0-9]\.ts'>nul && (do ...) || do ...
```

**Obs.:** When the current line contains the string `'output000.ts'`, we will remove the occurrences of **`'`** from the string, defining the line and using variable **`substring:'=nothing!`** already concatenated with the desired final string/line by  **`!_out:'=!`**

```bat
set "_out=%%~#" && cmd.exe /v /s /c "echo\mp3%%2Fmusic%%2F!_out:'=!?alt=media"
```

**4.** We will use a temporary file saving all the actions of the loop `>tmp.file (loop actions)`, and after finishing, we will overwrite this temporary file with the same name as the file used in the loop, using the move command:

```bat
>tmp.m3u8 (for /f ... )
>nul move /y tmp.m3u8 file.m3u8 ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. You have answered to question very clearly. This is first time I got to work with cmd. Even though I have not prior knowledge about cmd and the commands you have written, I could understand due to the way you answer. Thank you again.

Comment: @IsuruBandara Thank you for test the answer code too!